# How to evaluate $\int \frac{\cos x}{a-\cos x} \mathrm{d}x $ in a more elegant way?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I am trying to evaluate
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{a-\cos x} \mathrm{d}x \quad (1)$$

---

Since there is a ratio of trigonometric functions, I tried to reduce the problem to a polynomial ratio by using Weierstrass substitutions:

$$t = \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \iff x = 2\arctan(t)  \iff \mathrm{d}x = \frac{2}{t^2+1}$$

$$\cos x = \dfrac{1 - t^2}{1 +  t^2}$$

$$\sin x = \dfrac{2t}{1 + t^2}$$
Therefore from $(1)$:

$$ \int \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \frac{1}{a-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\frac{2}{1+t^2}\mathrm{d}t = a \int \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \frac{1}{1+(a+1)t^2} \mathrm{d}t $$

---

The function is a ratio such as: $\deg(1-t^2) = 2 < 4 = \deg((1+3t^2)(1+t^2))$ therefore we can break the relationship to partial fractions. We notice that the denominator has complex roots, therefore:

$$ \int \frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)(1+(a+1)t^2)} \mathrm{d}t = \cdots = \int -\frac{1}{t^2+1}+\frac{2}{(a+1)t^2+1} \mathrm{d}t$$

Therefore,

$$\int \frac{\cos x}{a-\cos x} \mathrm{d}x = -x + \frac{2a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} \tan^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}} \tan \frac{x}{2} \right) + C$$

---

I feel there is an easier way to evaluate this integral. Can you come up with one?

Comment: This is easy enough and standard.

Comment: Seems pretty elegant to me. Where is the problem?

Comment: @eminem The partial fraction calculation has been a mess. The system that needs to be solved in order to find the numerators needs time (4 variables). Question re-stated: I am wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: You are right, but in my experience partial fraction is almost _always_ a mess.

Comment: If there are real roots it is kinda easy. Complex roots are evil haha. Anyway, I think I should delete the question. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|a| > 1$.  Observe $$f_a(x) = \frac{\cos x}{a - \cos x} = \frac{(\cos x - a) + a}{a - \cos x} = -1 + \frac{a}{a - \cos x} = -1 + \frac{a}{a - (1 - 2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2})}$$ where we have employed the half-angle identity $$\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} = \frac{1 - \cos x}{2}.$$  Consequently
$$\begin{align} f_a(x) 
&= -1 + a \frac{1}{(a-1) + 2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}} \\
&= -1 + a \frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{(a-1) \sec^2 \frac{x}{2} + 2 \tan^2 \frac{x}{2}} \\
&= -1 + a \frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{(a-1)(1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}) + 2 \tan^2 \frac{x}{2}} \\
&= -1 + \frac{2a}{a-1} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{1+ \frac{a+1}{a-1} \tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}.
\end{align}$$
With the substitution $$u = \sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}}\tan \frac{x}{2}, \quad du = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}} \sec^2 \frac{x}{2} \, dx,$$ we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\int f_a(x) \, dx 
&= -x + \frac{2a}{a-1} \sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}} \int \frac{du}{1 + u^2} \\
&= -x + \frac{2a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} \tan^{-1} u + C \\
&= -x + \frac{2a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} \tan^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}} \tan \frac{x}{2} \right) + C.
\end{align}$$
Of course, I have taken the trouble to write out each step in detail which makes the solution longer than it really needs to be.

As an exercise for the reader, how is this approach modified if $|a| < 1$?

Comment: Apparently partial fractions are the easiest way, but its nice to see another solution, so I am accepting it.